# Declarations within an if statement

Tags: c

Are declarations within an `if` statement illegal without an enclosing brace? For example:

```
if (argc == 2)
    char* str = "Two";
else
    char* str = "Not two";
```

Would need to be converted to:

```
if (argc == 2) {
    char* str = "Two";
} else {
    char* str = "Not two";
}
```

Out of curiosity, why is this so? I understand the need for braces with multiple statements such as:

```
if (something)
    printf(something);
    printf(something);
```

Where the above really "means" the following in lieu of explicit braeces:

```
if (something) {
    printf(something);
}
printf(something);
```

But why is a single statement/declaration allowed, if it includes only a single `;`?

Comment: Your last piece of code is *not* ambiguous, by the way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, I mean it's wrong in terms of my intent -- I want the `printf` to only occur within the `if` statement but here it's occurring outside it. But yes, it's not ambiguous to the compiler, perhaps my language isn't precise enough in the question. Anyways -- I've removed that word, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, it comes from the grammar - [C11 A.2.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.3) - it's `if (..) statement` and `statement` can be `compound-statement` which is `{ block-item-list }` and `block-item` can be a `declaration`. It's the same as how `switch (1) { case 1: int a; }` is invalid. But as to _why_... it's just how it is. I guess it was so so that writing compilers is easier - if there's no `{`, there are no variables to allocate.

Comment: If it did allow a declaration there, what do you think the scope of the declaration would be? If it's the containing block, you would have two declarations for the same variable, which isn't allowed.

Comment: And if it's not the containing block, you would have a declaration of a variable with no place to reference it, so it's useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of an `if` statement (with an `else` clause) is:

> **if** (expression) statement **else** statement

And this:

```
char* str = "Two";
```

Is not a statement but a **declaration**, therefore it's not valid in your first code snippet.

The second snippet with curly braces works because the braces denote a **compound statement**, and a compound statement may contain both statements and declarations within it.

Note however that even in the second case which compiles, the variable `str` defined in each sub-block goes out of scope once the `if` statement completes and cannot be referenced.  What you probably want is:

```
char *str;
if (argc == 2) {
    str = "Two";
} else {
    str = "Not two";
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
char *str;
if (argc == 2)
    str = "Two";
else
    str = "Not two";
```

Comment: great answer thank you. And yes regarding the second half of your answer -- actually that is my next question, which I just asked but it seems you already answered it!